# 1 large 5 small design layout css flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I achieve such a layout I am new to web dev and I got stuck for quite a while trying to figure out how can I do it? I have only worked with column layout with flexbox, this looks like it have a combination of other properties.

[image]

This is my html code:

```
<div class = "container">

    <div class = "card">
    <img src="images/cards.png">
    <h2>Gift Cards</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque expedita tempore quasi omnis a aut et totam illo fuga accusamus dolorum vero, ut harum consectetur. Minima molestias officiis culpa non sed dicta itaque. Et aliquam illo obcaecati molestias veritatis porro.
    </p>

    <p>Already have an Orange MyTunes Music Gift Card?</p>
    <hr>
    <a href="#">>Redeem</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no need for `flexbox` could already be solved with simply floating the image.

Comment: @tacoshy But `flex` is more professional. this is better than `float`.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi no it is not. The thing is, that `float` for aligning purpose to aling block-level-elements next to each other. That would be a mis-used hack. In that case `flexbox` should be prefered. `float` is for floatin an image within a text-block which is exactly the case here.

Comment: @tacoshy Does that mean we should use `float` whenever wants to align an image with some texts? and is better than `flex`?

Comment: No it depends on the situation and the use case. In this case float would be appropiate which makes it perfectly fine to use and is the more simple solution then to apply flexbox with different containers.

Comment: @tacoshy But I have heard `float` deprecated! your idea?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi that is complete BS. Where is your proof to that claim? neither MDN WebDosc nor W3C deprectaed this. And they proberly never will as there is no equivalent to a floating mechanic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
}

.card img {
  height: 400px;
  max-width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">

    <div class = "card">
    <img src="https://www.unfe.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/SM-placeholder.png">
    <h2>Gift Cards</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque expedita tempore quasi omnis a aut et totam illo fuga accusamus dolorum vero, ut harum consectetur. Minima molestias officiis culpa non sed dicta itaque. Et aliquam illo obcaecati molestias veritatis porro.
    </p>

    <p>Already have an Orange MyTunes Music Gift Card?</p>
    <hr>
    <a href="#">>Redeem</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not the best approach however,
I suggest you change HTML code to be like this:

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-img {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.card-body {
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="https://s6.uupload.ir/files/giftcard_scrj.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2>Gift Cards</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque expedita tempore quasi omnis a aut et totam illo fuga accusamus dolorum vero, ut harum consectetur. Minima molestias officiis culpa non sed dicta itaque. Et aliquam illo obcaecati molestias
        veritatis porro.
      </p>

      <p>Already have an Orange MyTunes Music Gift Card?</p>
      <hr>
      <a href="#">>Redeem</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `flex`:

```css
.card{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.img{
  width: 40%;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
}
.text{
  width: 40%;
}
.text p{
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="img">
  <img src="https://s6.uupload.ir/files/magearray-giftcard-icon_n30.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
  <h2>Gift Cards</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque expedita tempore quasi omnis a aut et totam illo fuga accusamus dolorum vero, ut harum consectetur. Minima molestias officiis culpa non sed dicta itaque. Et aliquam illo obcaecati molestias
    veritatis porro.
  </p>

  <p>Already have an Orange MyTunes Music Gift Card?</p>
  <hr>
  <a href="#">>Redeem</a>
  </div>
</div>
```